# Problem in responsiveness of my portfolio

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I just have a doubt in responsiveness of a website.

While I was developing my portfolio, I just ran into some confusion. In my chrome browser, while I was coding for the responsiveness (media-queries), the zoom percentage was at 50%. I didn't notice that, I made my portfolio adjustable at 1300px, 1500px, 1800px and greater than 1801px. And the output was good.

After finishing only, I recognised that the browser zoom level was at 50%. And when I increased the zoom level to 100%, everything got bulkier and awkard to see (as expected).

I just want to know whether I have to change my whole code to zoom level 100% ???? OMG !!!! that's a tedious task.

Please say "You don't need to do that child, there is another way !!!!"
I would be happier if you guys say that

Comment: Please provide some code. This cannot be solved without code given. Thanks.

Comment: this can't be solved with code....Problem is.. my browser level zoom percentage is 100%, but when i go to dev tools (responsive design mode), there is a zoom section saying 52%,if i click on it and select 100%, it is not showing 4k monitor layout. (I understand, becoz my monitor is small, it is adjusting the zoom percentage)..... but...............

Comment: how can i test the 2000px responsiveness with 52% zoom level ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/w8mxIDD  ..... see in this pic above... 52%

Comment: Check my answer below...did that answer your question?

Comment: You misunderstood my question,

Comment: you can change the device so the width is 2000px....thats what you said you wanted to test....

Comment: man man man,,,, now i got it.. Because our screen width is small (1368px mine), it cant able to display the 2400px layout. So what they're doing is, reducing the zoom level of the web page and making it 2400px.

Comment: ok .........I see

Answer (score -1):

```css
@media and (max-width: 1800px) and (min-width: 1300px){
html{
min-width: 100%;
}
   }
```

This may be able to help.

Comment: if i give 50%, no change

Comment: It just means when your browser is between 1300 and 1800px, all your content will be 100% width.

Comment: i just changed it to 50% width, it doesnt affect anything.

Comment: Ok, I might have misunderstood your problem then. Please provide some code. It will help

Answer (score -1):

To do what you want to do just change what device is there. [image]

To do what you want to do click 'inspect' then click on the little phone icon next to elements. Then if you go even further left, you will see what device width and height you are looking at which you can change. You can also change the percentage.